# In the Spell “Guards and Wards” is there a size limit on the doors that can be affected as per the limitations on Minor Illusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Under the “Door” subsection of “Guards and Wards,” we have:

> Doors. All doors in the warded area are magically locked, as if sealed
>   by an arcane lock spell. In addition, you can cover up to ten doors
>   with an illusion (equivalent to the illusory object function of the
>   minor illusion spell) to make them appear as plain sections of wall. (PHB 248)

and for Minor Illusion, it says:

> If you create an image of an object-such as a chair, muddy footprints,
>   or a small chest-it must be no larger than a 5-foot cube (PHB 260)

Does this mean you can only ward 5 foot tall by 5 foot wide doors?  Or does it apply enough Minor Illusions to cover any sized door?

Comment: I cleaned up your question's formatting a bit. Don't forget that we have special quote formatting that you can apply when making long quotes from text. It makes your question easier to read and thus easier to answer well.

Comment: The natural language used in this system leads us to believe that every little detail is an actual rule, I think that is not what was intended, albeit it a byproduct of 3.X/PF.

Comment: That’s the general idea I’ve been getting around here.  Each word was used deliberately and carefully.

Answer (score 7):

## It should cover doors of any size

> you can cover up to ten doors with an illusion (**equivalent to the illusory object function of the *minor illusion* spell**) to make them appear as plain sections of wall.

What the spell is saying is that a door *is* covered with an illusion that is equivalent to the illusion we find in *minor illusion*. That sets up a bit of a conflict because the rules of *minor illusion* don't allow it to cover any doors greater than 5ft tall. If you look at the real world, the average door size is about 6'8" x 3"<sup>1</sup>.  If this restriction (and average door size) were to hold true in this case, the spell would not be able to cover almost any door.

Logically, the spell says that one of its primary functions it that it *does* cover doors. Thus, in order to function properly, the spell must be read as overriding the size limitation of *minor illusion*. It seems reasonable in this light to think that by saying "you can cover [the doors]" the spell is actually explicitly (albeit unclearly) saying that the illusion *will* cover the door and otherwise has the properties outlined by *minor illusion*. By saying this, the door-covering function of the spell makes sense and becomes useful. And, as a result of this reading, there is also no restriction on the size of doors that can be covered.

---

<sup>1 - There are no rules that say this is the case in the fantasy worlds of D&D. However, D&D is full of creatures that are much bigger than medium so, if anything, in many areas the door size could actually be greater than the real-world average.</sup>

Comment: ...and it explicitly says “cover up to ten doors with AN illusion.”

Comment: @NautArch I have updated. See if that clears things up.

Comment: I simply think that it should be read without the parenthetical section altogether as it only confused matters. @NautArch the comment is no longer there but if halflings can't forge a longsword that is "their size" why are they allowed to make a door "their size"? :P

Comment: What if it only covered up-to only 10 regular door's worth of doors?

Comment: That's a little different from covering "10 Doors." That would imply a limit of one door that was less than 10 Doors square, which would exclude doors of a certain huge size.

Comment: It should depend on how you define size. In the minor illusion spell you can interpret a 5ft cube as being 125 cubed feet of object, or as being no larger than 5ft in any direction.

Comment: @illustro a 5 foot cube is not the same as 125 cubic feet, the latter is usually called out in the spell description if this is allowed. Areas are defined in the Spellcasting section in the PHB.

Comment: This has its own question now so let us not debate it here please.